# What happened to Gordian III in the Battle of Misiche?

Tags: roman-empire, persia

I read in the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gordian_III) that: "Roman sources do not mention this battle (Battle of Misiche) and suggest that Gordian died far away from Misiche, at Zaitha (Qalat es Salihiyah) in northern Mesopotamia." but "Persian sources claim that a battle occurred (Battle of Misiche) near modern Fallujah (Iraq) and resulted in a major Roman defeat and the death of Gordian III." So, I want to know what is the accepted view on the Gordian III death based on opinion of modern historians?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the sources below it looks as if he was killed by his soldiers at the age of 19. This actually has a few more sources in there to look through.

https://www.britannica.com/biography/Gordian-III

https://www.britannica.com/place/ancient-Rome/Intellectual-life-of-the-Late-Republic